# How to use fail2ban to ban all php and cgi-bin requests

Tags: apache-httpd, fail2ban

On daily basis I see Apache log full of requests initiated by different vulnerability scanner apps. Those hundreds of requests from usually same IP addresses not only makes the log dirty but also uses some server resources.

As I do not have any PHP nor CGI-BIN scripts on my Apache, I would like to use fail2ban to ban all those IP addresses on a first request, for a certain amount of time.

Does any one have such ready-to-go fail2ban configuration?

Comment: [There's one on the wiki that should work for you](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Apache) I'm specifically talking about the PHP one. If there aren't any valid php scripts requests for them should all throw 404's.

Answer (score 5):

Thank to Joel comment here is the solution I currently use.

To `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` this is added to the end:

```
[urlscanners]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = urlscanners
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
maxretry = 1
bantime  = 86400
```

File `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/urlscanners.conf` is like this:

```
#block port scanners
[Definition]
failregex = [[]client (?P<host>\S*)[]] (File does not exist): .*(w00tw00t|CFIDE|php|cgi-bin|htdocs\.7z|htdocs\.rar|htdocs\.zip|root\.7z|root\.rar|root\.zip|www\.7z|www\.rar|wwwroot\.7z)
ignoreregex =
```

Paths may vary on different OSes.

Comment: Instead of appending those lines to jail.conf, put them in jail.local. https://serverfault.com/a/639941/270385

Answer (score 0):

Getting this on Fedora 28 (updated to show more lines):

```
2018-08-29 16:19:58,135 fail2ban.jail           [31014]: INFO    Creating new jail 'urlscanners'
2018-08-29 16:19:58,135 fail2ban.jail           [31014]: INFO    Jail 'urlscanners' uses pyinotify {}
2018-08-29 16:19:58,150 fail2ban.jail           [31014]: INFO    Initiated 'pyinotify' backend
2018-08-29 16:19:58,153 fail2ban.filter         [31014]: ERROR   No failure-id group in '[[]client (?P<host>\S*)[]] (File does not exist): .*(w00tw00t|CFIDE|php|cgi-bin|htdocs\.7z|htdocs\.rar|htdocs\.zip|root\.7z|root\.rar|root\.zip|www\.7z|www\.rar|wwwroot\.7z)'
2018-08-29 16:19:58,154 fail2ban.transmitter    [31014]: WARNING Command ['set', 'urlscanners', 'addfailregex', '[[]client (?P<host>\\S*)[]] (File does not exist): .*(w00tw00t|CFIDE|php|cgi-bin|htdocs\\.7z|htdocs\\.rar|htdocs\\.zip|root\\.7z|root\\.rar|root\\.zip|www\\.7z|www\\.rar|wwwroot\\.7z)'] has failed. Received RegexException("No failure-id group in '[[]client (?P<host>\\S*)[]] (File does not exist): .*(w00tw00t|CFIDE|php|cgi-bin|htdocs\\.7z|htdocs\\.rar|htdocs\\.zip|root\\.7z|root\\.rar|root\\.zip|www\\.7z|www\\.rar|wwwroot\\.7z)'",)
2018-08-29 16:19:58,154 fail2ban                [31014]: ERROR   NOK: ("No failure-id group in '[[]client (?P<host>\\S*)[]] (File does not exist): .*(w00tw00t|CFIDE|php|cgi-bin|htdocs\\.7z|htdocs\\.rar|htdocs\\.zip|root\\.7z|root\\.rar|root\\.zip|www\\.7z|www\\.rar|wwwroot\\.7z)'",)
2018-08-29 16:19:58,155 fail2ban.filter         [31014]: INFO    Added logfile: '/usr/local/etc/httpd/logs/error_log' (pos = 819643, hash = 01289652cb6817b4a991911956c7aa9a160eb60b)
```

Comment: please check the jail.conf file that under [urlscanners] that paths are correct. For example on Debian they are: logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log

Comment: No such luck path to log file is correct see updated logs in my post.

Comment: Have you updated the logpath parameter to reflect your apache configuration?

Comment: Yes logpath  = /usr/local/etc/httpd/logs/*error_log.ls -l /usr/local/etc/httpd/logs/*error_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1270058 Aug 30 14:45 /usr/local/etc/httpd/logs/error_log

Comment: Could you please paste the filter file urlscanners.conf?

Comment: cat /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/urlscanners.conf 
`#block port scanners
[Definition]
failregex = [[]client (?P<host>\S*)[]] (File does not exist): .*(w00tw00t|CFIDE|php|cgi-bin|htdocs\.7z|htdocs\.rar|htdocs\.zip|root\.7z|root\.rar|root\.zip|www\.7z|www\.rar|wwwroot\.7z)
ignoreregex =`